# use underscore for each in express application

Tags: javascript, express, coffeescript

i have this coffee script code:

```
  dirs = ["/assets", "/public", "/locales", "/data/topo"]
  app.configure ->
      app.use assets(build : true)
      jsPaths assets, console.log
      @use(express.favicon(process.cwd() + "/assets/images/favicon.ico", {maxAge:maxAges}))
      .use(express.compress())
      .use(express.static(process.cwd() + "/assets", {maxAge:maxAges}))
      .use(express.static(process.cwd() + "/public", {maxAge:maxAges}))
      .use(express.static(process.cwd() + "/locales", {maxAge:maxAges}))
      .use(express.static(process.cwd() + "/data/topo", {maxAge:maxAges}))
      .use(express.logger('dev'))
      .use(express.errorHandler(
            dumpException: true
            showStack: true
      ))
  #  Add template engine
```

i would like to set the maxAge for all the `dirs = ["/assets", "/public", "/locales", "/data/topo"]` , what is the correct way to do this?

any advice mush appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a method for every array item?

```
setMaxAge folder for folder in ["/assets", "/public", "/locales", "/data/topo"]

setMaxAge(folder) ->
  app.use express.static( process.cwd() + folder, maxAge:maxAges )
```

or a one-liner:

```
app.use express.static(process.cwd() + folder, maxAge:maxAges) for folder in ["/assets", "/public", "/locales", "/data/topo"]
```

Have a look at the [coffeescript documentation for loops](http://coffeescript.org/#loops)